# How to Refresh tabs of iframes when i change tabs in HTML

Tags: html, iframe, refresh

I have developed tabs using div tag. Assume that you are in "Tab2" which has "Page2.html".

As soon as i click on "Tab1", "Page1.html" has to get refreshed/reloaded.

This is how i created the tabs.

```
    <ul class="TabbedPanelsTabGroup">

        <li class="TabbedPanelsTab">Tab1</li>

        <li class="TabbedPanelsTab">Tab2</li>
    </ul> 
   <div class="TabbedPanelsContentGroup">


       <div class="TabbedPanelsContent">

            <iframe src="Page1.html"></iframe>  
       </div>
    <div class="TabbedPanelsContent">
            <iframe src="Page2.html"></iframe>  
       </div>         
   </div>
</div>
```

var TabbedPanels1 = new Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels("TabbedPanels1");

Comment: your question is unable to understand. Please explain it in detail.

Comment: Assume that i am in "Tab2". As soon as i click on "Tab1",the page "Page1.html" has to get reloaded/refreshed.

Comment: ok, See the answer i gave you.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your head tag of iframe's html page

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
```

Hope it will work.